# How to figure out the shell's drag/drop icon size for use with SHDoDragDrop?

Tags: c, winapi, drag-and-drop, icons, imagelist

How do I figure out the right icon size to use so that the icon matches Explorer's default drag-and-drop icon?

(I'm trying to use it with `SHDoDragDrop` if that matters.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size depends on what's in the data object format. From the Shell, it's 96x96.

You can check that if you drag & drop a file into any valid drop target, the data object will contain the "DragImageBits" format and its data is a [SHDRAGIMAGE structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ns-shobjidl_core-shdragimage):

```
typedef struct SHDRAGIMAGE {
  SIZE     sizeDragImage; // will contain 96x96 when dragged from the Shell
  POINT    ptOffset;
  HBITMAP  hbmpDragImage;
  COLORREF crColorKey;
} SHDRAGIMAGE, *LPSHDRAGIMAGE;
```

If you're looking for a more static way, here is a code that seems to work, using the UxThemes API. Note that although it uses documented APIs and defines, I don't think it's documented as such.

```
...
#include <uxtheme.h>
#include <vsstyle.h>
#include <vssym32.h>
...

// note: error checking ommited
auto theme = OpenThemeData(NULL, VSCLASS_DRAGDROP);

SIZE size = {};
GetThemePartSize(theme, NULL, DD_IMAGEBG, 0, NULL, THEMESIZE::TS_DRAW, &size);

MARGINS margins = {};
GetThemeMargins(theme, NULL, DD_IMAGEBG, 0, TMT_CONTENTMARGINS, NULL, &margins);

// final size
size.cx -= margins.cxLeftWidth + margins.cxRightWidth;
size.cy -= margins.cyTopHeight + margins.cyBottomHeight;

CloseThemeData(theme);
```

As for DPI settings, I understand you want to mimic Explorer, in this case you'll have to do some computation by yourself depending on your needs and screen context, as the image size extracted by the Shell is itself fixed.

Comment: Oh wow I see, thanks!! I'm actually confused what the clipboard has to do with dragging here - I don't deal with the clipboard when calling `SHDoDragDrop`, so can I ask where it comes into play? It's been kind of confusing figuring out how drag/drop is supposed to work. I also don't get how to figure this out at runtime. And I can't just hard-code 96x96 since it seems to be scaled by the DPI, which becomes per-monitor, etc... any idea what the right way to proceed here is?

Comment: I really mean "data object" :-) the image size is always the same even with other DPI settings

Comment: Hm, I don't think it's always 96x96. On my machine it seems to be 115x115 (which is 96 at 120%). You can actually see that in my screenshot; the length paper in my icon is already larger than 96 pixels. I noticed I can do `GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX)` to get this value, so that's what I'll do for now I guess, but it might end up getting messed up multi-monitor support. Makes me curious if there's a right way to do this. It seems to be hard to find good code samples.

Comment: Wow, fascinating! Thanks so much, looks like this doesn't even seem to need DPI adjustment anymore. Can I ask how in the world you figured this out?! It seems so random to have to reach for UxTheme!

Comment: Wow. Thanks! :-)

Comment: You know what, it looks like the UxTheme approach isn't quite correct ;) the icon is slightly too large and gets chopped off if it's too large. Best option seems to be falling back to `LOGPIXELSX`.